# Recommendation for simple project/task time tracking app

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, time-tracking

I'm looking for a very simple app to allow me to track my time on particular user-defined **projects** or **tasks**.

However, my requirement is slightly different to those in questions such as [Is there a good time automatic time tracking tool for Mac OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40631/is-there-a-good-automatic-time-tracking-tool-for-mac-os-x) as I don't need something that will automatically track my time spent in particular applications such as [Time Sink](http://manytricks.com/timesink/) or [Time Track Pro](http://bloop.it/timetrack/). Rather, what I want to be able to do in a rough "must have" to "nice to have" order is:

- Add user-defined projects/tasks to a list each with its own timer
- Manually start and stop project/task timers as I switch projects
- Idle timer to stop recording activity if I leave the computer for a period of time
- Access the app from the menubar (ability to hide dock icon would be a bonus too)
- Create subtasks from the main project/task

So, apologies in advance for the following, but in my head the interface might look something like the following, but again I'm **totally open to suggestions**:

```
Project          Time
---------------------
Project X        0:32   <Start/Stop Button>
Project Y        4:00   <Start/Stop Button>
Project Z        1:25    
    Subtask 1    1:00   <Start/Stop Button>
    Subtask 2    0:25   <Start/Stop Button>
```

For example, [Harvest](http://www.getharvest.com/mac) looks perfect for what I need, apart from the fact that there's a $12 per month cost. I'm not against paying for an application, but I'd like to avoid ongoing charges if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end, I found [Timecop](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/timecop/id466285239?mt=12) that does almost everything I wanted: simple project tracking with a variety of configurable reports spanning days, weeks, or months.

[image]

Honourable mentions go to [Tictoc](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tictoc/id412307572?mt=12) which does a very similar job to Timecop, and [Timing](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/timing-time-tracking-for-humans/id431511738?mt=12) (which also has a free, [Lite version](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/timing-lite-free-time-tracker/id467410757?mt=12)). Timing is different in that its a "traditional" application tracker, however, you can create custom projects and drag applications into them, right down to the document level. So you can attribute different documents in a single app to different projects, which is great if you're working on two different projects in Xcode, for example.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but it looks like [On The Job](http://stuntsoftware.com/onthejob/) is the application you are looking for. It will cost you money as well, but a one time license will provide you with a full version.

Another (paying) app is [Office Time](http://www.officetime.net/index.php). Great in syncing with multiple platforms (PC, Mac, and iOS) and does a job similar to On The Job, mentioned above.

I can think of a third application which will suit your needs, but I can't remember the name. I'll keep thinking and upate my answer as soon as I know it!

Comment: Thanks! Yes, thats the sort of thing I'm after, but perhaps those "enterprise class" apps are a bit overkill for what I need. As its just for my personal projects, I probably won't need all the billing and invoicing features - but they do have task timers and I'm happy to take all suggestions nonetheless :)

Answer (score 2):

I would check out [TSheets time tracker](http://www.tsheets.com). They have a free single user account, it is simple to set up with your job codes and click back and forth between projects, and although they have an extensive list of [time tracking features](http://www.tsheets.com/overview-of-online-timesheet-software.php) you can customize your account to be as basic as you'd like. I have been very pleased with this company.

Answer (score 2):

I use [hr - Task Timer](http://www.hrmacapp.com) which is very similar to Timecop and Tictoc, but free.

Answer (score 0):

On the Job is good but lacks reporting.  Trying Officetime now and it looks like exactly what I need for non-billing time tracking.  Super simple, inexpensive and has reporting.

Comment: This is a bit vague, could you add more information?

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option: [Toggl](https://www.toggl.com). They offer free and paid plans.