# Is there an app I can use to track screen time for each desktop on my MacBook?

Tags: desktop, screen-time, productivity

In general I work on a specific desktop and I do other stuff on the other ones. So I would like to track the screen time of that specific desktop in order to know for how long I have been working. How can I measure this?

Cheers.

Comment: @agarza there they are not addressing the desktop tracking.

Comment: Not sure there is a way of doing this, maybe a third-party app?